# Transfer Matrix Method to determine the generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Let $G = (V,E,\Phi)$ be a weighted directed graph and $\mathcal{W}' : E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the weighting. Let additionally $m = \# V$, $E_m$ the $m \times m$ identity matrix. Let $v,w \in V$ be in a fixed order in $V$ so $v$ is the *i*-th and $w$ the *j*-th element of $V$. Then applies
>
> $$f_{vw}(x) = (-1)^{i+j} \det((E_m - xA)^{(j,i)}) / \det(E_m-xA).$$
>
> **Example**:
>
> Let $L$ be the set of all words over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$ that no not contain "bb". The following unique finite state-machine with the start state $S = q_0$ and final states $T = \{q_0,q_1\}$ accepts exactly these language:
>
> [image: state-machine 1]
>
> we now use a weighting $W'(e) = 1$. The matrix of the graph is given by
>   $$\mathcal{A} = \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1 \\
>                    1 & 0 
> \end{array}
> \right) 
> $$
>   while the first row and column relate to the node $q_0$ and the second row and column to the node $q_1$. Then applies for $f_L(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \sum_{w \in L \atop |w| = n} x^n$ that $f_L(x) = f_{q_0q_0}(x)+f_{q_0q_1}(x)$.
>   Because of $$\det(E_2-Ax) = (1-x)-x^2$$  we get using the the transfer-matrix-method (see definition above)
>
> $$f_{q_0q_0}(x) = (-1)^{1+1} \det((E_2-Ax)^{(1,1)})/\det(E_2-Ax) = 1/(1-x->x^2).$$ 
>   $$f_{q_0q_1}(x) = (-1)^{1+2} \det((E_2-Ax)^{(2,1)})/\det(E_2-Ax) = (-1) \cdot (-x)/(1-x-x^2).$$ 
>   Therefore applies
>   $$f_L(x)=f_{q_0q_0}(x) +f_{q_0q_1}(x) = \frac{1+x}{1-x-x^2}.$$
>
> **Exercise**
>
> Let $g_n$ be the amount of words of the length $n$ over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c\}$ that contain max two b's.
>
> (a) Use the transfer-matrix-method to determine the generating function $\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n$
>
> (b) Determine an explicit formula for $a_n$

I created the finite state machine for the given language as

[image: state-machine 2]

$$
\mathcal{A}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0  \\
    0 & 1 & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

\begin{align*}
    f^G_{11}(x) &= \frac{ (-1)^{1+1}\det((E_m - xA)^{(1,1)})}{\det(E_m-xA)}\\
       &=\frac{\det\left(\left(
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 & 0  \\
         0 & 1 & 0  \\
         0 & 0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}-
        \begin{pmatrix}
         x & x & 0  \\
         0 & x & x  \\
         0 & 0 & x  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \right)^{(1,1)}\right)}
        {\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 & 0  \\
         0 & 1 & 0  \\
         0 & 0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}-
        \begin{pmatrix}
         x & x & 0  \\
         0 & x & x  \\
         0 & 0 & x  \\
        \end{pmatrix} \right)} \\
       &=\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}^{(1,1)}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
       &=\frac{1}{(1-x)}\\
   \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    f^G_{12}(x) &= \frac{ (-1)^{1+2}\det((E_m - xA)^{(2,1)})}{\det(E_m-xA)}\\
       &=\frac{-1\det\begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}^{(2,1)}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{-1\det\begin{pmatrix}
         -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{x(1-x)}{(1-x)^3}\\
       &=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
   \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    f^G_{13}(x) &= \frac{ (-1)^{1+3}\det((E_m - xA)^{(3,1)})}{\det(E_m-xA)}\\
       &=\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}^{(3,1)}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
         -x & 0  \\
         1-x & -x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}\\
       &=\frac{(-x)^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
       &=\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
   \end{align*}

Also: 
\begin{align*}
    f(x)&=f^G_{11}+f^G_{12}+f^G_{13}\\
    &=\frac{1}{(1-x)}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
    &=-\frac{1}{(x-1)}-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-1)^3}\\
   \end{align*}

Is this right? And how can i solve b)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The finite state machine is correct. But note, the entries $a_{i,j}$ of the transition matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{0\leq i,j\leq 2}$ count the *number of possibilities* to walk in one step from state $q_i$ to state $q_j$. Since we can go from $q_0$ to $q_0$ either via $a$ or $c$, we have two possibilities and therefore
$$a_{1,1}=2$$
The same holds true for $a_{2,2}$ and $a_{3,3}$. The state transition from $q_0$ to $q_1$ and the transition from $q_1$ to $q_2$ is done via $b$, so that $a_{1,2}=a_{2,3}=1$.

> We conclude the matrix $A$ is 
>   \begin{align*}
> A=
> \begin{pmatrix}
>     2 & 1 & 0  \\
>     0 & 2 & 1  \\
>     0 & 0 & 2  \\
> \end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since we consider words containing exactly two $b$'s, all valid words are  generated when starting in state $q_0$ and ending in state $q_2$. Therefore we need to calculate only $f_{13}^G$.

*Note:* This is a difference to the example in OPs question, where *both states* are end states.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
    f(x)=f^G_{13}(x) =\frac{\det\begin{pmatrix}
         -x & 0  \\
         1-2x & -x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}{\det
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1-2x & -x & 0  \\
         0 & 1-2x & -x  \\
         0 & 0 & 1-2x  \\
        \end{pmatrix}}
       =\frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^3}\\
   \end{align*}

To determine an explicit formula of the coefficients $a_n$ of the generating function $f(x)$ we use the formula of the *[Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*

> \begin{align*}
> \frac{x^2}{(1-2x)^3}&=x^2\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-3}{n}(-2x)^n\\
> &=x^2\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+2}{n}(2x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+2}{2}(2x)^{n+2}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 2}\binom{n}{2}(2x)^n\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

Comment:

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-k}{j}=\binom{k+j-1}{j}(-1)^j$
- In (2) we use $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$
- In (3) we shift the index $n$ by $2$

> We conclude $a_n$, the number of words of length $n\geq 2$ is 
>   \begin{align*}a_n=\frac{1}{4}\binom{n}{2}2^n=2^{n-3}n(n-1)\qquad\qquad n\geq 2\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

**Hint:** It's often a good idea to verify the problem for small $n$ manually

\begin{align*}
S_2=\{&aa\}\\
S_3=\{&aab,aac,aba,aca,baa,caa\}\\
S_4=\{&aabb,abab,abba,baab,baba,bbaa,\\
&aabc,abac,abca,baac,baca,bcaa,\\
&aacb,acab,acba,caab,caba,cbaa,\\
&aacc,acac,acca,caac,caca,ccaa\}
\end{align*}

and we see: 
\begin{align*}
|S_2|&=a_2=1\\
|S_3|&=a_3=6\\
|S_4|&=a_4=24\\
\end{align*}

in accordance with the result (4).