# Generating function of Language is rational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, rational-functions

Let W be the set of all words over an alphabet $\Sigma$. Let $$L=\{w\in\Sigma^* | w\neq uvu',\text{ with }u,u'\in\Sigma^*,v\in W\}$$

I have to show that the generating function of L is rational.

My first problem is to understand the language. I think this language contain nor words !

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $L=\varnothing$. Thus, if $\ell(n)$ is the number of words of $L$ of length $n$, we have $\ell(n)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Is this function $\ell$ a rational function?

Comment: The generating function of a language L is a rational function if L is regular. Because the empty Language L is regular thats mean that $\ell$ ist rational

Comment: @Noah: True, but you don’t need that theorem here: just observe that any constant function is rational, so the zero function is rational.

Comment: ok thank you very much

Comment: @Noah: You’re welcome.

Comment: @brian-m-scott can you see this question please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337526/transfer-matrix-method-to-determine-the-generating-function ?